# Swift CORDIC Algorithm gives constant answer

Tags: swift, trigonometry

I tried to translate the MATLAB language on [Cordic wikipedia webpage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC)

However when I type those:

```
print(cordic(beta: Double.pi/9, n: 20))
print(cordic(beta: Double.pi/8, n: 20))
```

I get

```
[-0.17163433840184755, 0.98516072489744066]
[-0.17163433840184755, 0.98516072489744066]
```

It's always giving me a constant answer. Why? I'm sure that the "angle" and "Kvalues" arrays are properly calculated.

Here's the code:

```
import Foundation

var angles: [Double] = []

for i: Double in stride(from: 0, to: 27, by: 1) {
    angles.append(atan(pow(2, -i)))
}
var Kvalues: [Double] = []

for i: Double in stride(from: 0, to: 23, by: 1) {
    Kvalues.append(1/sqrt(abs(Double(1) + pow(2,-2 * i))))
    if i > 0 {
        Kvalues[Kvalues.count - 1] *= Kvalues[Kvalues.count - 2]
    }
}
func min(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    return a > b ? b : a
}
func cordic(beta: Double, n: Int) -> [Double] {
    var beta1 = beta
    let Kn = Kvalues[min(n, Kvalues.count - 1)]
    var v: [Double] = [1,0]
    var poweroftwo: Double = 1
    var angle = angles[0]

    for j in 0 ..< n {
        let sigma: Double = beta < 0 ? -1 : 1
        let factor: Double = sigma * poweroftwo
        v = [v[0] - v[1] * factor, v[1] + v[0] * factor]
        beta1 -= sigma * angle
        poweroftwo /= 2
        angle = j + 2 > angles.count ? angle / 2 : angles[j + 2]
    }
    return [v[0] * Kn, v[1] * Kn]
}
print(cordic(beta: Double.pi/9, n: 20))
print(cordic(beta: Double.pi/8, n: 20))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the same result for different input because in

```
let sigma: Double = beta < 0 ? -1 : 1
```

`beta` should be `beta1`, which is the local variable that is
updated in the loop.

But even after fixing that the results are not correct, and that is
caused by two "off-by-one" index errors. The arrays in the [algorithm
description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC#Software_example) are 1-based and Swift arrays are 0-based. So

```
let Kn = Kvalues[min(n, Kvalues.count - 1)]
// should be
let Kn = Kvalues[min(n-1, Kvalues.count - 1)]
```

and

```
angle = j + 2 > angles.count ? angle / 2 : angles[j + 2]
// should be
angle = j + 1 >= angles.count ? angle / 2 : angles[j + 1]
```

The `angles` and `Kvalues` arrays should be defined for `i` from 0 up to *and including* 27 resp. 23.

Finally, there is no need to define your own `min` function as there is one in the Swift standard library.

Putting it all together your code would be:

```
var angles: [Double] = []

for i: Double in stride(from: 0, through: 27, by: 1) {
    angles.append(atan(pow(2, -i)))
}
var Kvalues: [Double] = []

for i: Double in stride(from: 0, through: 23, by: 1) {
    Kvalues.append(1/sqrt(abs(Double(1) + pow(2,-2 * i))))
    if i > 0 {
        Kvalues[Kvalues.count - 1] *= Kvalues[Kvalues.count - 2]
    }
}

func cordic(beta: Double, n: Int) -> [Double] {
    var beta1 = beta
    let Kn = Kvalues[min(n-1, Kvalues.count - 1)]
    var v: [Double] = [1,0]
    var poweroftwo: Double = 1
    var angle = angles[0]

    for j in 0 ..< n {
        let sigma: Double = beta1 < 0 ? -1 : 1
        let factor: Double = sigma * poweroftwo
        v = [v[0] - v[1] * factor, v[1] + v[0] * factor]
        beta1 -= sigma * angle
        poweroftwo /= 2
        angle = j + 1 >= angles.count ? angle / 2 : angles[j + 1]
    }
    return [v[0] * Kn, v[1] * Kn]
}
```

And that produces good approximations:

```
print(cordic(beta: Double.pi/9, n: 20)) // [0.93969210812600046, 0.34202155184390554]
print(cordic(beta: Double.pi/8, n: 20)) // [0.92388022188807306, 0.38268176805806309]
```

The exact values are

```
print(cos(Double.pi/9), sin(Double.pi/9)) // 0.939692620785908 0.342020143325669
print(cos(Double.pi/8), sin(Double.pi/8)) // 0.923879532511287 0.38268343236509
```